# Reading remote control signals from java application

Tags: java, controls, serial-port

Can I write a java application that uses [RxTxComm](http://users.frii.com/jarvi/rxtx/) 
to get signals from a remote control send to my serial receiver?

I have a RS-232 receiver I am listening on that com port for incoming bytes.

When I press any button on my remote control I don't see any data arriving to my serial port.

What am I missing here?
Should I see any data?

How does [lirc](http://www.lirc.org/) do it ?

Answer (score 0):

It is sovled here: http://commjava.blogspot.com/ have a look at it. (Be aware that they use proprietary third party code)

Lirc is not in java, their solution won't help you.